# FullCalendar 3.4.0. Получить список смежных событий

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим,
С 12:45 до 13:45 - 1 событие.
С 13:00 до 13:45 – 2 событие.
С 13:00 до 13:30 – 3 событие.
Все за одну дату (как на картинке).

Как я могу получить id всех событий, которые будут пересекаться по времени с новым событием, если я создаю событие, например, с 12:30 до 13:30? Или 13:30 до 13:45?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что вот так:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if(event.start <= date && event.end >= date) {
                    alert(event.id);
                }
            });
    }
});
```